# Oracle Datapump Export is very slow

Tags: performance, oracle11g, export, datapump

My Oracle 11.2.0.3 FULL DATABASE Datapump Export is very slow, when i ask V$SESSION_LONGOPS

SELECT  USERNAME,OPNAME,TARGET_DESC,SOFAR,TOTALWORK,MESSAGE,SYSDATE,ROUND(100*SOFAR/TOTALWORK,2)||'%' COMPLETED FROM V$SESSION_LONGOPS
where SOFAR/TOTALWORK!=1

it show me 2 records, in opname one containing the SYS_EXPORT_FULL_XX, and another "Rowid Range Scan" and the message for the last one is

Rowid Range Scan : MY_SCHEMA.BIG_TABLE: 28118329 out of 30250532 Blocks done and it takes hours and hours.
I.E :  MY_SCHEMA.BIG_TABLE is a 220 GB table size having 2 CLOB colunn.

Answer (score 1):

If you have CLOBs in the table it will take a long time to export because that wont parallelize. Exactly what phase are you stuck in? Could you paste the last lines from the log file or get a status from data pump?

There are some best practices that you could try out:

- SecureFile LOBs can be faster than BasicFile LOBs. That is yet another reason for going to SecureFile LOBs.
- You could try to increase the STREAMS_POOL_SIZE to 256 MB (at least) although I think that is not the reason.
- Use PARALLEL option and set it to 2 x CPU cores. Never export statistics - it is better to either export using DBMS_STATS or regather at target database.

Regards,
Daniel

Comment: Processus esclave 2 Statut :
  Nom de processus : DW01
  Statut : EXECUTING
  SchÚma de l'objet : MY_SCHEMA
  Nom d'objet : BIG_TABLE
  Type d'objet : DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
  Objets terminÚs : 1
  Nombre total d'objets : 11 474
  Lignes terminées : 141 580 469
  Parallélisme de processus esclave : 1
  
  for the 3 others process, status is : WORK WAITING

Comment: Is it possible to increase worker process parallelism? could it ameliorate the datapump performance?
  Actually PARALLEL option is enabled and it is = 4, my production server has a 16 cpu  and 2 parallel_threads_per_cpu   
  cpu_count 16
  parallel_threads_per_cpu 2

Comment: Daniel,  by "Use PARALLEL option and set it to 2 x CPU cores. Never export statistics - it is better to either export using DBMS_STATS or regather at target database." => do you think that increasing this parameter from 4 to for example 8 or 12 or may be 16 will increase datapump performance and decrease the total export duration actually taking +10 hours?

Comment: If I understand the log extract correctly the data pump operation is still exporting the table data which means that you are probably waiting for the LOBs. There is not much more you can do - neither with the parallel option. The LOBs goes out in one process.

Comment: Thank you for your reply
My BIG_TABLE has + 150 Million records, if I purge the contents of the CLOBS columns by putting a null value for for example 25% or 30% of the rows, do you think that will reduce the size of the table? to free up space in the tablespace? to reduce the export duration?

Comment: I am not sure that the table itself will necessarily be smaller but the export should be faster. Otherwise, partitioning the table will help, I am quite sure.

Answer (score 0):

Well for 11g and 12cR1 the Streams AQ Enqueue is a common culprit for this as well.  If you ALTER SYSTEM SET EVENTS 'IMMEDIATE TRACE NAME MMAN_CREATE_DEF_REQUEST LEVEL 6' this will help if the issue is the very common Streams AQ Enqueue.